# Is it possible to name a dependency with StructureMap?

Tags: dependency-injection, .net-4.0, structuremap

I would like to be able to inject named dependencies into a class using StructureMap if that is at all possible. The main reason I want this right now is for connection string injection.

I may be doing this the wrong way, but here's how I've got it (just need to add injection now):

psuedo:

```
public class MyServiceClass
     string connectionString;

     public MyServiceClass(string connectionString)
          this.connectionString = connectionString;

     public void DeleteObject
          var db = new EntitiesObject(connectionString)
```

Is there any way to put a name on the connection string constructor parameter so that StructureMap would know how to inject it?

**EDIT:** I could have multiple connection strings that are determined at run-time from a configuration database.

**EDIT:** One solution I've thought of is to create a ThisDatabaseConnectionString and a ThatDatabaseConnectionString class... that way it could inject the connection string based on type

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (assuming that `myConnectionString` is a string instance):

```
container.Configure(r => r
    .ForConcreteType<MyServiceClass>()
    .Configure.Ctor<string>().Is(myConnectionString));
```

If you also need to map MyServiceClass from an interface (or abstract base class), you can do this instead:

```
container.Configure(r => r
    .For<IServiceClass>()
    .Use<MyServiceClass>()
    .Ctor<string>().Is(myConnectionString));
```

---

If you have previously configured named connection strings configured in the container, you can do something like this:

```
container.Configure(r => r
    .For<string>()
    .Use("foo")
    .Named("connStr1"));
container.Configure(r => r
    .For<string>()
    .Use("bar")
    .Named("connStr2"));
container.Configure(r => r
    .ForConcreteType<MyServiceClass>()
    .Configure.Ctor<string>().Is((IContext ctx) => 
        ctx.GetInstance<string>("connStr2")));
```

Comment: Could potentially need two different connection strings (not likely, but it happens)... I guess I'll probably go with my idea of creating a class for each connection string needed.

Comment: Couldn't you just select the appropriate connection string imperatively as part of your container setup?

Comment: I don't want the container setup to have to specify each place this connection string will be used. Unless I'm missing somethin.

Comment: It sounds like you want to make a convention-based setup of connection strings? If so, you may want to take a look at this: http://groups.google.com/group/structuremap-users/browse_thread/thread/6db0963489511d5c